# How to upload through django admin

Tags: python, django, upload

```
    documents = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.FILE_PATH, verbose_name=
_('Attach Your Documents'), help_text=_('.pdf file not exceeding 5 mb.'), 
null=True, blank=True)
```

By this way i am creating a models for the `upload` of a file in `django admin`. Now I want to upload this file to `S3` when some one click `save` on `django admin`. Where should i write the methods for `uploading` to s3. I am not getting any idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [django-storages](http://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home)