# Multiple pdf upload from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating an application in django where I want to upload multiple file from django admin. I also want these files to be associated with a particular user in my database. for e.g a pdf file will have a file names as 'john.pdf', 'matt.pdf', 'alice.pdf' and I want to upload all these files at once from django admin and each file should be associated with particular user, so if user john logs in he can see pdf 'john.pdf' in his profile page.
I am new to django and web programming and I have been banging my head for a couple of days but I just cannot find the right logic to implement such a code. 
I have looked in these resources but I still cannot really find an answer
[How to upload multiple file in django admin models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343413/how-to-upload-multiple-file-in-django-admin-models)
[How to upload through django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301824/how-to-upload-through-django-admin).
I am using django with mysql database. I highly appreciate and thank anyone in advance who could help me out with this problem. (hoping not to get downvoted too much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out a solution but I still don't know if thats the best solution there. What I did was to add path of my pdf files in MySQL database and add attributes to those paths. I wrote a script in python to add those files to MySQL database. My script listed all the files in the directory, where the files were stored and added them to the database. From these attributes I could retrieve those paths. As these are just paths to static files I had to save them in the static folder for django to access and display them and the rest was simple.